# Cannot start a ps1 file with BATCH using `call` or `start`

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

Ive got issues with a batch command that wont start whatever i was to do about it, even using `call` wouldnt start it.

```
:choice2
set /P c1="text here [Y/N]? "
if /I "%c1%" EQU "Y" start "" /wait /high /max "Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File %batdir%batch\filename.ps1"
if /I "%c1%" EQU "N" goto :end
goto :choice2
```

Main requirement is that the %batdir% is in the first `if` line, because the batch runs from a flash drive.

Tried without `%batdir%`, wouldnt work either way.
Tried using different commands for the powershell.exe, tried using a direct `dir` of powershell, wouldnt work, always getting the "Cannot find file, make sure it is typed in properly.".

I would appreciate any help anyone could provide.

Comment: try separating the program name and arguments, ie. `... powershell.exe "-executionpolicy remotesigned -File %batdir%batch\filename.ps1"`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! General advice: Please provide any error messages or other symptoms of the problem. What exactly does happen? Specific advice: Are you missing a `goto` in the `Y` branch? Why is the first parameter of `start` an empty string?

Comment: Please also read how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

As you have not provided a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), this assumes that `%batdir%` was the location of the running batch file, which I've replaced with the appropriate `%~dp0` variable. You should also note that I've also replaced your `set /p` command, because that is not the correct command to use for known single key input:

```sh
:choice2
"%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe" /M "text here"
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo end
Start "" /Wait /High /Max "%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "%~dp0batch\filename.ps1"
GoTo choice2

:end
Pause
```

I do not recommend the use of `/High` or `/Max` for this task, *(including them only because you did)*. So because you said you also tried `call`, it seems to me as if you probably don't need to use `start` with those options either. If you just need to run the powershell script and wait for it to complete, before returning to the input prompt, try this modification:

```sh
:choice2
"%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe" /M "text here"
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo end
"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "%~dp0batch\filename.ps1"
GoTo choice2

:end
Pause
```